# Feeling of very large skybox in Unity and Oculus Rift

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, skybox

In our VR trainer scene created in Unity3d we have a vehicle and we are used real 360 degree panorama taken from one camera to create evironment inside a cabin.

Everything goes fine except feeling of gigantism of the environment in VR.

How i can avoid this effect?

This feelings came up only in headset, when i looked at the monitor surface everything looks fine...

screenshot:

[image]

Comment: You could instead apply it maybe to a Sphere and place the camera inside that sphere? the Skybox is ment to be "infinite" far away...

Comment: @derHugo thank you for suggesting, in this setup it looks little different, but bigger that in life too..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO it's because of the missing stereo information in your Skybox. The depicted room looks so narrow that in reality you would have differing views for each eye.

Projecting the image on a sphere instead doesn't solve that problem. A big enough sphere will look exactly like a skybox, a small sphere would provide stereo information, but still your texture doesn't, which will make it look like a flat wallpaper on a narrow sphere :)

Comment: it is absulutely true, at now i has other approach to reach stero effect (depth information)

Comment: Hi @StrangerintheQ

Could you please provide some info as to what approach you have taken to solve this issue. We are struggling with the same problem and desperate to find a solution. 

Thanks.

Comment: @DP001 уоu need separate images to both eyes,

Comment: thank you for such a quick reply @StrangerintheQ
our videos and photos have already filmed, so i guess there is no easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You could try creating an object(cube or sphere), putting the texture on that object, and then put the camera inside that object.  The smaller the object, the less 'expansive' it will feel. Careful not to make it too small otherwise the other objects will look like they're going into a wall.

The reason *why* it feels expansive is because the screen is right up to your face in VR. This is very noticeable in games like Super Hot or Job Simulator when comparing it to the monitor.

Comment: thank you for suggesting, in this setup it looks little different, but bigger that in life. too, i've already created next step: sphere with bump inside by depth texture